# Confirm collection exists using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

New to MongoDB so I hope I get the terminology correct...

I have a database that includes a user collection. In node I would like to check that value of a field, however, first I need to ensure the field exists.

For example here is my user schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    local: {
        email        : String,
        password     : String,
    },
    facebook         : {
        id           : String,
        token        : String,
        email        : String,
        name         : String
    }
}
```

Some users have both a local and facebook documents/fields? whereas others may have either.

I wish to confirm the is the current user document has an email value in both fields if both fields exist in the document. i.e.

```
User.local.email & User.facebook.email
```

If I try to access the email field directly and the field does not exist for that document I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
var localExists = User.local != null;
var facebookExists = User.facebook != null;

if(localExists && facebookExists){
    // both exist so check if both have email
    var bothHaveEmail = User.local.email != null && User.facebook.email != null;
}
else if(localExists){
    // only local exists
}
else if (facebookExists){
    // only facebook exists     
}
else{
    // nothing exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
const localEmail = user.local && user.local.email;
const fbEmail = user.facebook && user.facebook.email;
```

If either is set to `undefined` that means that that email field doesn't exist